# How to fetch FLAGS of an email using IMAP libcurl?

Tags: imap, libcurl

I want to get `FLAGS` of an email that I fecthed with libcurl.

How can I design the url?
I just can get header and mime body, not including `FLAGS` of individual mail with current code.

Even though I searched through RFC documents, 
I couldn't find any examples on url scheme which can also fetch `FLAGS`.

If you can provide me with some tips on the url, I would appreciate it.

Comment: You may be able to use the CUSTOM REQUEST (see examples for creating a folder and the like with UID FETCH [uid] (FLAGS)), and just run the command manually, and interpret the result.  The examples are a little unclear as to what kind of result you can expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FLAGS` can't be fetched via libcurl, in part because they can't be addressed using a URL. The RFC says what can be addressed:

> The IMAP URL scheme is used to designate IMAP servers, mailboxes,
>   messages, MIME bodies, and search programs